# Pass data to a command handler

Tags: winapi, atl

I have an ATL CMenu class that implements a popup window with several options for the user to click.

When the user clicks a menu option, that option is mapped to a command ID with an associated handler.

Is there a way I can pass the title (string text of the first entry) of the CMenu class to the command handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the handler receives control being mapped by an identifier ([`WM_COMMAND`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591) parameter) only. As soon as you have the identifier and [if] you know what menu it came from, you can locate the item of interest and read back it's text.

Comment: It could come from several different menus - which one is only known at run time.  I coded around the problem but my solution is not optimal...